# What is going wrong with my attempt to Cherry Pick using SourceTree?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I am tasked to use SourceTree for some Cherry-Picking.  In learning how to do this, I created the simplest project I could think of:  a single text file that contains the word “Sunday.”  I put this under source code control with SourceTree/Git, in the master branch.

Then I created a feature branch off of master, and made three commits, adding:  1) Monday, 2) Tuesday, and 3) Wednesday.

Then I used the Cherry Pick feature to pick the second commit, Tuesday, into master. My goal was to have the single file, in master, contain “Sunday” and “Tuesday.”

I got a conflict and nothing I tried could resolve the conflict. No choices on the “Resolve Conflicts Menu” did anything that solved the problem.

I expected the text file in master to contain:

Sunday
Tuesday

That was not what happened. Am I missing a key concept here?  Did I expect it to work in a way it does not, and will never work?

This diagram shows what I tried to do, with the messages received from SourceTree:

[image]

Comment: `I got a conflict` ... what did your text file look like exactly at the moment you tried to do the cherry-pick?  Note that Git can sometimes auto resolve conflicts, and that, sometimes the resolution might go counter to what you would expect.

Comment: You do understand, don't you, that your "actual result" is a conflict file and is easily resolved by direct editing? If you want it to say Sunday Tuesday, then make it so and mark it resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conflict probably has to do with newlines. If you typed "Sunday" with no newline after, and committed that, and then you typed a newline and "Monday", that is not merely an addition of a line "Monday"; it is a *removal* of the "Sunday" line and an *insertion* of "Sunday\nMonday". That's a potential conflict.

But also, your expectations *are* wrong. You're not going end up with "Sunday Tuesday" by cherry-picking the Tuesday commit. That commit also contains Monday!

(Do not let yourself be confused by the notation in the merge file; the word "Tuesday" at the end is not the content of anything, but is the commit message you applied to the Tuesday commit.)

One final comment: I don't quite see what you mean by this:

> No choices on the “Resolve Conflicts Menu” did anything that solved the problem.

If you select the file in SourceTree and look at the resolve conflicts menu, you have a choice between Ours and Theirs. It would be quite reasonable to resolve using Theirs.

Comment: I understand, as you said, "... your expectations are wrong."  But there is no issue with the newlines, as you suggested. So I still don't understand what caused the conflict.  But the "theirs" did, in fact, resolve the conflict.

Comment: That's great, but you should also be unafraid to edit the document by hand to resolve the conflict. It's easy. Merge conflicts are a fact of life; they should not scare you.